# Q: mysql - trigger insert other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

If I have a table called `test1` and have

```
a , b variable
```

then another table called `test2` have

```
c variable
```

then how can I `update c(test2) where a + b(test1`) from trigger?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean when a row a,b is inserted into table test1 you want a trigger to insert a row c into test2 which is the sum of the two elements inserted into test1?

Comment: yes, that's it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the below url for the solutions :
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Hope this will help!